# When does fast travel become available?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

At what point in the story do Oliver and company gain the ability to travel quickly around the map, and are there any limits to the fast travel mechanic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fast Travel is achieved through a spell called Travel, and allows you to instantly teleport to any previously visited location. The spell is unlocked a couple dungeons after unlocking the boat, and is a reward for completing a dungeon.

> More specifically, it is a gift from the Great Sage Marcassin after completing The Tombstone Trail dungeon, located near Hamelin.